# Как прописать абсолютный путь в Cron для установления тайминга скрипта

Tags: php, веб-программирование, cron, crontab

Прописываю разные варианты:

```
/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/layouts/modern/parser_std.php
/myTheme/inc/layouts/modern/parser_std.php
```

и т.п., играя со слэшами, но получаю сообщение на почту: Could not open input file:
Подскажите, как правильно прописать?

Comment: у вас прям в корне диска находится каталог `/public_html/` ? И почему вы уверены, что ругается на него, а не на `include` внутри этого файла?

Comment: @ArchDemon в первом скрипте я скопировал вообще полный пусть от public_html, ниже которого ничего нет и до parser_std.php . В письме приходит - Could not open input file:/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/layouts/modern/parser_std.php

Comment: *ниже которого ничего нет* — не может быть. каталог `public_html` вряд ли кто-то в здравом уме расположит в корне файловой системы. скорее всего, он находится в домашнем каталоге какого-то пользователя. вот и укажите **полный** путь. что-нибудь вроде `/home/пользователь/public_html/и/далее/по/списку` // ну и «запускать» лучше не файл, а всё-таки интерпретатор: `php /путь/к/файлу.php`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin может, я путаю что, но путь начинается именно с /public_html/wp-content... то есть выше уровня нет, некуда переходить через файловый менеджер.

Comment: какой ещё «файловый менеджер»? в терминале прямо наберите: `$ ls /public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/layouts/modern/parser_std.php`. ругается? значит, нет такого пути. ну и интерпретатор не забудьте указать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а откуда мне взять home/пользователь ?

Comment: понятия не имею. откуда вы вообще взяли этот путь: `/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/layouts/modern/parser_std.php`? // [википедию почитайте, например](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83), про абсолютный и относительный пути к файлу/каталогу.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin с помощью $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; я получил родительскую директорию, теперь путь стал таким: /home/t/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/layouts/modern/parser.php   . Но вообще не приходит никаких уведомлений на почту, но стоит мне переименовать файл в #parser.php , как тут же на почту приходит, что не может Cron открыть его. А до этого открывал или что, раз никаких уведомлений не приходило?

Comment: знаете анекдот про долго молчавшего английского ребёнка? «всё было в порядке, вот я и молчал». с программой cron примерно та же ситуация.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я понял в чём дело. Уже не в пути, а в самом скрипте. Он ничего не выводил, а просто молча передавал информацию дальше. Как только я что-то вывел - инфа с выводом пришла мне на почту. Спасибо! Кстати, анекдот про английского ребёнка - как раз в точку)